# Notebook starts formatting content automatically and then collapses

Tags: plotting, front-end, notebooks, version-13

I am working on a notebook of size 5 MB which contains only data and `Plot` or `ListPlot` on WIN64 with MMA13.3.

I am experiencing issues with this Mathematica notebook where it begins formatting content automatically by showing a dialog saying *"Formatting Notebook Contents"*, taking a long time, and then collapsing, see screenshot below.

[image]

Working with MMA12.3 on the same notebook, such a thing never happened.

Comment: It's hard to test without the code. What is new in v13 and affects the performance is [`PlotHighlighting`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotHighlighting.html). Try using `Plot[ ..., PlotHighlighting -> None]`.

Comment: I may have had this problem too. I believe it's related to the dynamic callout things they added where you can put the mouse on points or lines in the plot and it will show the value as you scrub over it. Try disabling ''Dynamic Updating Enabled' from the Evaluation menu. 
Also if you don't want to do that, try adding `PlotHighlighting -> None` to your plots to get rid of the callouts as Domen already mentioned.

Comment: @Domen, `PlotHighlighting -> None` magically works, I have working now for 1 hour and everything is fine before it happens every few minutes.

Comment: @flinty, is it possible to make the default `PlotHighlighting -> None` without adding in each plot?

Comment: Yes, it is possible: `SetOptions[Plot, PlotHighlighting -> None];` I guess this question could deserve an answer, since it might be happening often for users coming to v13.

Answer (score 10):

The reason you see a significant slowdown is the introduction of [`PlotHighlighting`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotHighlighting.html) in version 13.3, which is turned on by default and controls the appearance of highlighting features of plots when you mouse hover over them.

You can turn it off by using `PlotHighlighting -> None` inside your `*Plot` functions. To disable it generally, use [`SetOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html):

```
SetOptions[Plot, PlotHighlighting -> None];
```